# Effective data/rows queuing out of database

Tags: c#, architecture, enterprise-architecture, distributed-computing

A component in a system (called Notifier) inserts hundreds of messages ~300 (SMSs) per second in a table in MSSQL database with PENDING status by flagging a column called `status` with `int` value `0`.

Another component (called Dispatcher) which is a console app published on 3 servers and it runs through Windows Scheduled Task every 20 seconds on all machines level *(i.e. it runs every minute for each server as per the following: 1st server at 12:00:00, 2nd server at 12:00:20 and 3rd server at 12:00:40)*.

This console starts by running an SQL command like this:

```
UPDATE M
SET RetryCount = RetryCount + 1
OUTPUT
DELETED.MobileNumber,
DELETED.Text
FROM MessagesTable M
WHERE RetryCount < 3 AND Status = 0
```

The app uses `Parallel.ForEach` to iterate over all fetched messages and start pushing it to an SMS gateway and update the `status` column in db with `1` in case of success and `-1` in case of failure.

This model has 3 issues:

1. `UPDATE` command can cause some locks in db, especially it fetches all PENDING messages regardless how many messages are ready to be fetched and dispatched.
2. Some messages can be lost due to crashed in application or so.
3. Sometimes (during peak time), the messages are 3x, so the load will be tripled at that case, which means the there will be a delay in delivery, so this is a scalability issue.

We have been requested to revamp this component by coming up with a model which allows scalability, stability and resiliency.

We came up with a solution which fetches the messages and push it to **SQS** which triggers a **Lambda function** which takes care of pushing the message contents to the telecom gateway.

Actually, I didn't feel that part is the best one to follow, because we are depending on the same console with the same external calls (to SQS), in addition, the same `UPDATE` command is there.
So, we suggested to reduce the headache in db Read/Write node, and just selecting the pending messages from read-only db node, and keeping the external call to SQS as is, but we figured out that this can lead to multiple consoles fetch the same row as per the the following scenario:

- 12:00:00 > **Console A** got 1000 row (IDs from 5000 to 5999)
- 12:00:20 > 700 rows got flagged as SUCCESSFUL by **Console A**, and still 300 ones are under processing, then Console B is triggered and it fetched 800 messages *(500 new + 300 old which are already picked earlier by **Console A**)*
- ... etc.

The above scenario shows the issue of fetching the same row by multiple instances which leads to have redundant processing for the same message.

> Any idea to get out of this model by suggesting a serverless model which helps to have a scalable, stable, faster and resilient system?
>   I tried to see how Amazon or any online ordering platforms deal with their giant amount of orders, but I didn't find something!

Note: we have tried MSSSIS for getting and transforming the data, then push it through AWS SNS > SQS > Lambda, but this also led to fetching the data twice if the second round of fetching contains a row/message which was fetched by first round but not flagged as SUCCESSFUL in db (which means under processing)!

Comment: The first thing I would question is whether the messages need to be stored in the database at all.

Comment: Actually, that component which inserts messages into db is a legacy code, and it is too difficult to play with it at the mean time (logic is inside in stored procs). That's why we started thinking about other components instead